# Swift loop through array

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to loop through an array with coordinates and show markers on a map with this code:

```
                for index in 0...3 {

                    let latitude: Double = latCoordinate.objectAtIndex(index) as! Double
                    let longitude: Double = longCoordinate.objectAtIndex(index) as! Double

                    let  position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
                    print([latitude],[longitude])
                    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                    marker.title = "Hello World"
                    marker.map = self.mapView

                }
```

But I just get one marker on the map, it should be 4. Why can't I see the other markers on the map?

Comment: Is the print statement run 4 times?

Comment: can you provide your debug information - print([latitude],[longitude]) ?

Comment: I just get one value when printing: print([latitude],[longitude]) Like this: [52.822329] [17.21232]

Comment: dont know swift, but isn't `let` used to declare constants? I think you should be using `var` instead

Comment: so, if I get it right... you are regenerating your __one and only__ `marker` multiple times in the cycle and you don't have any clue about why you have idea why you will have ___only one___ `marker` when you have ___only_ one__ `marker`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good for displaying the marker, but are you sure the coordinates are correct?  - Just looked at the comments again and the issue is in how you're populating your array, if you only have one coordinate in your array then you're only going to see one marker on the map.

This code from my app adds all the coordinates to a GMSCoordinateBounds and then sets the GMSMapView camera to the bounds of all the coordinates - so everything should be visible on the displayed map.

```
func plotAll(){
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds.init()
    for property in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!
    {
        let capitalAsset : CapitalAsset = property as! CapitalAsset
        let marker = GMSMarker.init()
        marker.draggable = false
        marker.snippet = capitalAsset.address
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(capitalAsset.latitude!), Double(capitalAsset.longitude!))
        marker.position = location
        marker.map = mapView
        // Update bounds to include marker
        bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }

    let camera = mapView.cameraForBounds(bounds, insets:UIEdgeInsetsZero)
    mapView.camera = camera;

}
```

Hope that helps.